# Cannot clone from gitlab with SSH

Tags: ssh, gitlab, git-clone

I recently installed gitlab on an ubuntu 18.04 LTS instance. I am trying to clone a repo from GitLab.
My ssh config file is as below :

```
# ~/.ssh/config
User git
Hostname gitlab.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I have added the ed25519 public key to SSH keys in GitLab. When I try to clone the repo i get this issue-

```
$ git clone git@xxxx:root/test-project.git
Cloning into 'test-project'...
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong? I have checked out a couple of links on the internet but I cant figure out what I have done wrong.

I am able to clone and push if I use http instead of ssh.

```
 git clone http://xxxx/root/test-project.git
Cloning into 'test-project'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Why does http work and not ssh?

Comment: I have already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64100419/3437897

Answer (score 0):

You have your ssh `clone` statement wrong: `git clone username git@example.com:root/test.git`

That statement would try to clone a repository named `username` into the location relative to your current path, `git@example.com:root/test.git`.

You want to leave out `username`:

```
git clone git@example.com:root/test.git
```

Comment: Also You can do this with your SSH entered:```git clone https://username@github.com/username/repository```

Comment: I am using the link as is mentioned in GitLab. when I clink clone this is the link it gives.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is Using sourcetree it will hit all the git clone and update command for you in just a click and also gives you a rich graphical representation on your repo and branches