# I am trying to fetch data from gitlab i am facing error

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to fetch my website content from git lab but unfortunately i am facing error please check below and how can i resolve this issue thanks.

```
   git fetch
    kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: where will i check a correct access sir ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue after I  switched remote URL of git repo from SSH to HTTPS. My guess is that this is occurring because of some security conditions imposed by GIT server.

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url

Comment: You can replace the git ssh with https in config file (inside .git folder) and it should work.